# Rhino Mock - Stubbed method always returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nunit, rhino-mocks, rhino-mocks-3.5

I've been trying to figure out what is happening with this particular test that I'm writing and now reaching out again to see if someone might know what is going on.

I have a ModeltoXml method that when I test via another test class directly, it's fine.  However in another method I'm testing which makes a call to ModeltoXml my stub created in Rhino Mock always returns null.

Below is roughly how my code looks for the test where I pass my stubbed methods in via the constructor.

```
[Test]

   var newEntry = new Model1{name="test"};
       var referrer = "http://example.com";

       var stubbedConfigMan = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IConfigurationManager>();
       var supportMethods = MockRepository.GenerateStub<ISupportMethods>();
       stubbedConfigMan.Stub(x => x.GetAppSetting("confEntry1")).Return("pathhere");
       supportMethods.Stub(x => x.ModeltoXml(newEntry)).IgnoreArguments().Return("test"); //this is the line of code which should be setting the return value

 var testObject = new MyApi().NewTicket(newEntry, referrer, supportMethods, stubbedConfigMan);
```

The concrete method that is invoked for this test has a line which looks like this:

```
 public MyResponseModel NewTicket(Model1 newTicket, string referrer,     ISupportMethods supportMethods,IConfigurationManager configMan)
{
//.. other code here
   var getXml = supportMethods.ModeltoXml(newTicket);  //This line always returns null
}
```

A simple entry for the ModeltoXml method:

```
public string ModeltoXml<T>(T item)
{
//Code here to serialize response

       return textWriter.ToString();
   }
```

And what I have on my interface:

```
public interface ISupportMethods
{
  string ModeltoXml<T>(T item);
}
```

I created another basic method which would except and return a string value.  I got this working in the same class however in the test I had to use the .IgnoreArguments option on the stub.  Thereafter when debugging I was seeing the set return value.

However when I tried doing the same on the problematic line of code in my test class, I still see no return value appearing in my class under test during debug.

So I'm a tad stuck!  I'm getting return values on other stubs in my test and it's this particular method/stub which just wont play ball.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

A more simple example of the above I've found is under the same test:

```
       var stubbedConfigMan = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IConfigurationManager>();
       var supportMethods = MockRepository.GenerateStub<ISupportMethods>();

        supportMethods.Stub(x => x.ModeltoXml(newEntry)).IgnoreArguments().Return("test").Repeat.Any();

//the class under test is successfully returning 'hero' when this method is called.
       supportMethods.Stub(x => x.mytest(Arg<string>.Is.Anything)).Return("hero");

//If I use this line and debug test9 is set with my return value of "test".
//However in the same run my class under test the method just returns null.
    var test9 = supportMethods.ModeltoXml(newEntry);

   var testObject = new MyApi().NewTicket(newEntry, referrer, supportMethods, stubbedConfigMan);
```

What the above examples shows is that passing my mocked/stub objects over to my class under test, something happens with the ModeltoXml stub.  I can't see/think of any reason why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

At last got this one sorted.   I had a feeling the problem was related to my use of generics in my ModeltoXml method.  I have simply used the Arg property in my ModeltoXml stub which has solved the problem:

```
  supportMethods.Expect(x => x.ModeltoXml(Arg<Model1>.Is.Anything)).Return("Model XML response");
```

I also used .Expect this time around so that I could assert the method was called but it will work with .Stub all the same.